# Problem setting class properties

Tags: c#, properties

I keep getting a null exception at the ; below.  The ApiUsername & ApiPassword have values so I don't undestand if I just set this up wrong or what.  The Credentials property is a certain type which has the Username and Password properties that need to be set.

So I have the auto-propery defined:
public CustomSecurityHeaderType SoapCallCredentials { get; private set; }

Then whenever this is hit, I get a null exception and can't figure out why.

```
private void SetApiCredentials()
{
    SoapCallCredentials = new CustomSecurityHeaderType
    {
        Credentials = 
        {
            Username = PayPalConfig.CurrentConfiguration.ApiUserName,
            Password = PayPalConfig.CurrentConfiguration.ApiPassword
        }
    };

    UrlEndPoint = PayPalConfig.CurrentConfiguration.ExpressCheckoutSoapApiEndPoint;
}
```

Comment: Are you missing `new` on your Credentials declaration?

Comment: I thought so but let me try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am thinking you need a new....

```
Credentials = new WhatEverThisTypeIs()
{
    Username = PayPalConfig.CurrentConfiguration.ApiUserName,
    Password = PayPalConfig.CurrentConfiguration.ApiPassword
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [eBay API Example](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/HowTo/FirstCall/MakingCallCSharp.html)

Credentials needs to be instantiated first, like:

```
Credentials = new UserIdPasswordType()
```